# how to find the ratio of a percentage?

Tags: probability

First things first, sorry if the title is just stupid or wrong but math has never been a strong part of my grades or life

second, i had no idea what to call it and i would appreciate it if: after reading the question that you would enlighten me on what topic is actually called.

the question/problem:
I have a game i'm creating a mod for, and when the player opens a box they will pull out 1 of 3 items.

-Item A has a 60% chance of being the one of the three items pulled from the box.

-Item B has a 30% chance of being the one of the three items pulled from the box.

-Item C has a 10% chance of being the one of the three items pulled from the box.

i however, want to add a forth item to the box so that the player will pull out one of the four items instead of one of the three items.

I want this fourth item to have a 5% chance of being pulled from the box.

rule 1: The sum of all chances cannot exceed or be less than 1
(such as 60+30+10=100 is fine) (60+30+10+5=105 is not fine)

so the question is, how do i remove 5% across all 3 items mathematically?

i do not:
want to just take 3% from A and 1% from B and then another 1% from C because i came to that conclusion by guessing and in the games files it's not 3 items but varies from box to box. meaning this box may have 3 items, but some other boxes have 16 and therefore it's not practical nor is it anything to be proud of to just eyeball it.

note:the numbers above are just random numbers i picked, as i need to apply this to several different boxes each with their own different number of items and with each item having their own unique percentage of being pulled.

Comment: How and why did you come up with 60, 30 and 10 in the first place.  And what aspects to you want to keep? That items 1 is twices as likely as item 2 and item 2 twice as 3 and three twice as 4?  If so item 4 = 5% is impossible.  What *exactly* do you want.

Comment: It completely depends on what you want the odds to be, so there is no "mathematical" way to decide unless you have a specific request (maybe what you are asking), such as keep the ratios the same with your numbers of 60, 30, 10, and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to keep the ratios the same with your "percentages" then you can find the fraction for each of the numbers out of the total, i.e., with the new total of 105 you have
$$
\frac{60}{105}
$$
$$
\frac{30}{105}
$$
$$
\frac{10}{105}
$$
$$
\frac{5}{105}
$$

Comment: both answers gave me what i wanted, i'm not sure which way is best though? either way, thanks guys.

Comment: It depends on if item 4 *must* be 5% no matter what the the others turn out to be or whether you are fitting in item 4 to be proportional to the to the other items.  If the latter Carser and my second answer are both the same.

Comment: Right @fleablood.  You can define the proportions to be whatever you want, so it just depends on what you want!

Comment: what i ultimately wanted was to fit #4 in and intentionally make it a rare item, without lop-siding the ratio of the original 3 items. the way i understand it, what i'm doing is just forcing something to fit in the best way possible with the 100% limitation.

Comment: Then either solution would work.  Carser's answer is pretty flexible.  You could say Item A has 30 chances.  B has 20 and C has 15 but 4 only has one.  Then you'd set A as 30/66, B as 20/66 and C as 15/66 and 4 as 1/66.  No need to hammer the numbers in or fudge anything.  Mine does the same but I assume you had a rough idea what the original idea of percentages in the first place.  Carser's answer doesn't assume you need to know any such thing.

Comment: There is nothing magical about the number "100".  If you reduce things to "parts" and you get 107 parts, or 98 parts or 217 parts... just use fractions 63/217 or whatever and convert to percentages.  No Magic.

Answer (score 0):

You want Probability of Item 4 = 5% and probability of NOT Item 4 = 95%.

I'm assuming[#1] you want if NOT Item 4 the probability of #1, #2, and #3 is 60%, 30%, and 10%.

In other words you want:

probability of #1: 60% of 95% = 57%.

probability of #2: 30% of 95% = 28.5%

probability of #3: 10% of 95% = 9.5%

Probability of #4: 5%.

Total 100%.

....

[#1] Or maybe I am wrong.

Maybe you what: Item # 1 is twice as likely as Item #2 which is 3 times as likely as item #3 which is twice as likely as item # 4.

In which case you want:

Item 4:  x%

Item 3:  2x%

Item 2:  6x%

Item 1: 12x%

So x% + 2x% + 6x% + 12% = 100%.  So 21x% = 100%.  So x = 4.76%

So Item 1: 57.15%

Item 2: 28.57%

Item 3: 9.52%

Item 4: 4.76%

===

Or did you what some other distribution?  What *exactly* would you like?

Comment: yes, the first 2 sentences had me alittle lost but the "other words" made total sense. thank you, the part that eluded me the most was that i didn't realize i needed to add the 3 items into 1 and subtract the 5% from there. last question, if i ever had to word this to someone else, whats it called? did i ask how to evenly subtract from percentages or would you call it something else?

Comment: There's no term for subtracting percentages because there is no reason anyone would want to do it.  If you had to subtract 30% from 75% and 25%  there is utterly no reason to subtract 15% flat rate from each to get 60% and 10%.  15% is a completely different proportion of 75% than it is of 25%.  Instead you need to subtract 30% **of** each.  Subtract 30% of 75% to get 52.5% and subtract 30% of 25% to get 17.5%.  There is no *word* for this.  This is simply calculating percentages.